# Need Suggestions for Words Abbreviation

Tags: abbreviations

I'm trying to translate some text from Chinese to English. For some certain circumstances, abbreviation for words are needed.

Here are the words need to be shortened:
Scout, Stealth, Stamina, Firepower, Armor, Lethal, Accuracy, Critical, Penetrate, Ricochet

All of words mentioned above need to be abbreviated to less than 4 letters. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that this is for some sort of game. I'm going to further assume that the players will understand what the shortened forms will represent based on the context of their use.

As you can only use three letters, the only logical system is to simply take the first three letters of each word.

Luckily, using the first three letters results in each being unique (*Ste* versus *Sta*, for example).

Comment: I would change _Sta_ to _Stm_, as it makes it harder to confuse the two. Lower case _e_ and _a_ can look quite similar at first glance, whereas _m_ is more different.